# Run python project without relative imports

Tags: python-3.x

There is a lot written about how to structure the files and folders in a Python project. It is also written that relative imports should avoided. But I do not see how.

Here is an example project structure (imagine this as an upstream code repository).

```
Foo
├── foo
│   ├── bar.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __main__.py
└── run.sh
```

The `__init__.py` is empty and just indicates that `foo` is a package.
I run the project with the `run.sh` script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
python3 -m foo
```

This is my `__main__.py` showing the two approaches to import `bar.py`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# works
#from . import bar
# do not work
import bar

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bar.do()
```

The point is that only the first (currently out commented) works. When I use the second one I got this error message when running `run.sh`.

```
ImportError: No module named 'bar'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that's because there *is* no `bar`.

Rather, it is `foo.bar`.

When run in the context of `foo`, the `.` dot indicates `foo`,
so `.bar` is `foo.bar`.

The solution in your MWE would be to modify the import line this way

```
from foo import bar
```